# Double redirect - implications on performance and cost

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cloudflare

I recently setup an AWS S3 account and hosted a static site there. I've setup one bucket for the 'www.example.com' and one for the apex domain 'example.com'.

The 'www.example.com' bucket redirects to the 'example.com' bucket. I have also setup a Cloudflare service which forces https on the domain.

So the chain is: http://www.example.com -> http://example.com -> https://example.com

Furthermore, I am leveraging CloudFront to distribute content globally to help reduce S3 costs. I've opted to not go the Route53 route, due to costs.

I'm wondering what the performance implications are, in terms of content delivery, as well as what the implications are relating to S3 resource costs, does each request(as per the chain above) equate to a GET.

Is there a better and/or more efficient way of doing this, relating to both cost and performance ? What are best practises to follow in this regard.

Things seem a little sluggish at the moment, while rendering a simple html page.

Thanks.

Comment: You could just setup the www.example.com -> example.com redirect in CloudFlare as well (as a page rule), removing the need for the bucket and the redirect rule in S3.

Comment: Hey Mark, Thanks for the feedback. Can I have some clarity on how I would achieve this ? Must I turn off redirecting and website hosting for the www.example.com bucket ? What would my CNAME settings change to, if example.com is the only one serving the static content ? A little new to all this.

Comment: Hi Mark, I managed to sort out the redirect on CloudFlare's side. Just letting you know. Thanks